# How to add custom UIView to Stackview on top of UIScrollView programmatically?

Tags: swift, uistackview

I have a ViewController that has a UIScrollView with a vertical UIStackView on top of it.
Everything works fine if i add UIView to the stackview with height constraint trough the interface builder.  For example 3 views with height 600px. If i run the app, i can scroll with no problem and see all three added views. The for the stackview works fine.

If i try to add a view to the stackview with code with addArrangedSubView trough code i can see that the first view that i added if i "force" scroll down, but not the other two.  It doesnt matter if i set height constraints to the views that i add, and it doesnt matter if i set intrinsicContentSize for the custom views.

How can i get the scroll view to expand the scroll area when adding trough code. ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Please provide your specific code segments so people can better help you!

Comment: Try to update your `UIScrollView` contentSize with `scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: <your-width>, height: <your-height>)` after you add the arranged subviews.

Comment: You need to provide a bit more information. Are you trying to add the scroll view, stack view and image views all via code? Or, have you added your scroll view with an empty stack view in Storyboard? If so, what constraints have you given to the stack view? Or, do you have just the scroll view in Storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess in lack of more information:

The issue may be related to the way constraints are set up between the scroll view and its child, the stack view.

you should add the following constraints:

- fix stack view edges (top, leading, trailing, bottom) to scroll view
- set width constraint between stack view and scroll view
- *also* set height constraint between stack view and scroll view, **set its priority to low (250)**

For more insights please read up on "setup UIStackView with auto layout", for example here:
https://medium.com/@pradeep_chauhan/how-to-configure-a-uiscrollview-with-auto-layout-in-interface-builder-218dcb4022d7

If it doesn't work please provide the relevant code and screenshots of your Interface Builder setup.